# No website opening but network works perfect, dns perfect as well

Tags: network, dns, websites

I am relatively new to OSX but I do my best here. I read a lot and tried to solve but did not find a answer which fits to my problem well.

I have a Mac Mini with Yosemite 10.10.2. My network seems perfect and I can ping for example in my Terminal any website, domain etc. also nslookup works perfect for any domain.

How ever if I try to open a website nothing opens and the page loads simply forever. I am connected either with Wifi or Cable but the same result. I tried to activate/disactivate  without success the network adapter. Of course I restarted modem as well. (Besides with my tablet and phone the same modem via Wifi works perfect).

I dont know what else to do. I also do not use any Antivirus, Firewall etc. software in this moment. How ever something blocks me from opening any website. the only thing which helps me is a complete restart of my system.

Thank you  in advance for any tip.

Comment: What happens if you just try an IP address in the address bar? For example http://17.172.224.47 should take you to Apple's website and http://2.127.237.152 should take you to Google.

Comment: That is a good question, I did not try this. I only tried to ping addresses and domains from Command. Next time I am stuck I check this. Do you have already a tip in case it works or does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your time and date are set correctly. Safari will have all sorts of trouble including with certificates when the time is off.

Comment: Time and Date are perfect. Also problem happen with all Browsers, Chrome, Firefox, Safari.